# Not able to configure ssp on MOSS 2007 server

Tags: sql-server, shared-service-provider

I am not able to configure ssp on MOSS 2007 server.

I found that OFFICESERVERS service was not running.

I checked system event log I got this error: `The SQL Server (OFFICESERVERS) service terminated with service-specific error 17058 (0x42A2).`

Answer (score 1):

Which sql server do you use?
if its 2005 try to look at this post - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/6b5b82e5-1346-4d59-86b0-7eaac7b930a7/

Comment: I am using 2005,i visited the above mentioned post but issue is that there is no path exist for master.mdf,mstlog.ldf and errorlog for officeserver instace.i am able to see the path for sqlexpress instance. Also i have 2005 and 2008 on same server.